# Session value from php to another php via ajax call

Tags: php, ajax

My main purpose is to recover forgot password after asking security question.

DONE:    I am checking for the email id(email id from the forgot password screen via ajax post method) in the database, If the email id exist I am getting the question and answer for that matched record in the session variable. After the success ajax call, I am redirecting to the security question page.

QUESTION:   I want to display the question from that session(forgot_password.php) in that question text box to ask them to type for the answer.

Any suggestions?

Comment: First suggestion: post your relevant code. Second suggestion: `echo "Question: " . $_SESSION['question'] . "<br />Answer: <input type="text" name="answer" />";`

Comment: How to pass that question and answer(from session) to next security_question.php after ajax success call?

Comment: Pass the question via the session and the answer via the POST'ed form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add question to the session array and access that from any session enabled page. You just need to make sure on security page you have this -

```
  <?php session_start(); ?>
```

at the top of everything. That's all. Access the session value and print it.